# Horizontal scroll bar not showing in panel

Tags: vb.net, panel, scrollbars

I've create a simple panel with a size of 500 x 500. I've also created another panel (inner_panel) with a size of 1000 x 10. I set it inside of the first panel. However, the first panel does not show any scroll bars. I've tried setting the autoscroll to true, but that didn't help. How do I get the horizontal scroll bar on the outer panel to show up?

```
Public Class test_panel

    Inherits Panel

    Private outer_panel As New Panel()
    Private inner_panel As New Panel()

    Public Sub New()

        With outer_panel
            .Parent = Me
            .Width = 500
            .Height = 500
            .BackColor = Color.Green
            .Location = New Point(0, 0)
            .AutoScroll = True
        End With

        With inner_panel
            .Parent = outer_panel
            .Width = 1000
            .Height = 10
            .BackColor = Color.Red
            .Location = New Point(0, 0)
        End With

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you missed adding the outer panel to the inner panel. `outer_panel.controls.add(inner_panel)`

Comment: actually, the .parent property of the inner panel does just that. I can see the inner panel inside the outer panel, I just can't see all of it because I have no scroll bars.

Comment: Code works.  Try making it a smaller panel so you can see it.  Or set the Dock property of the OuterPanel to fill.

Comment: Why doesn't auto scroll work without having to set the Dock property? I'd rather no set the dock property if I don't have to.

Comment: It does work, but your 500 pixel height outer panel is probably below the container panel, so you don't see the scroll bar.

Comment: It is not below the container. I can see the whole outer panel plus more area surrounding it.

Comment: Just change the height to 50 instead of 500.  I tested your code as posted.

Comment: That's interesting that it works for you because I don't have any scroll bars using this code.